# Maven resume from failed project on Jenkins

Tags: hudson, jenkins

Is there a way to configure Jenkins to resume a (broken) Maven build from where it failed the previous time it ran?

When working with large multi-module projects, it can be very annoying to have to wait a long time for all the unchanged projects to be build after submitting a small change to fix a broken build (e.g. add a missing import after a merge error).

It can of course be done by manually changing the build config to include the `-rf <module>` in the build-step, but I see at least two problems with this:

1. I don't want manual edits, it should be automatically.
2. There might be additional build-steps which I want to skip. (E.g building custom library jars)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to tell jenkins to do this automatically, unless there's a plugin that i don't know of that does that.

What you can do to make the process a little more smooth is to create a parameterized build which gets as a parameter the correct module you want to run, so when you click build you could have a drop down menu or something similar to choose from.